# Selection box of composite component not drawn properly

Tags: delphi, controls, vcl

I have a composite component that consists of a `TEdit` and a `TButton` (yes, I know about `TButtonedEdit`) that inherits from `TCustomControl`. The edit and button are created in its constructor and placed on itself.

At designtime the selection box is not drawn properly - my guess is that the edit and button are hiding it because its been drawn for the custom control and then overdrawn by them.

Here the comparison:

[image]

I have also seen this for other 3rd party components (like the TcxGrid also only draws the outer part of the selection indicator)

Question: how can I change that?

Most simple case for reproducing:

```
unit SearchEdit;

interface

uses
  Classes, Controls, StdCtrls;

type
  TSearchEdit = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    fEdit: TEdit;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Custom', [TSearchEdit]);
end;

{ TSearchEdit }

constructor TSearchEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  fEdit := TEdit.Create(Self);
  fEdit.Parent := Self;
  fEdit.Align := alClient;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Which version of Delphi, in case it matters

Comment: But I don't think you are going to have any luck. I think that the selection indicators are implemented by the IDE hooking the control window procedures.  And your control is painted before its children.

Comment: Probably the easiest, off the top of my head, is to setup your own painting for design time.

Comment: @Gray you mean do the painting in the parent, and suppress child painting?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, use something like `fEdit.PaintTo(...)` in the parent at design time and paint directly to the parents canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the easiest thing I can think of is to paint the controls in the parent and "hide" them from the designer at design time. You can do this by calling [SetDesignVisible(False)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.SetDesignVisible) on each of the child controls. Then you use [PaintTo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.PaintTo) to do the painting on the parent.

Using your example we get:

```
type
  TSearchEdit = class(TCustomControl)
  ...
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  ...
  end;

constructor TSearchEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  fEdit := TEdit.Create(Self);
  fEdit.Parent := Self;
  fEdit.Align := alClient;
  fEdit.SetDesignVisible(False);
end;

procedure TSearchEdit.Paint;
begin
  Inherited;
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    fEdit.PaintTo(Self.Canvas, FEdit.Left, FEdit.Top);
end;
```